# Oracle EZConnect in Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

Mediawiki supports Oracle and I'm trying to configure it in the installer.

The installers says you can use EZConnect...something like:

```
user/pass@//server.example.com/dbname
```

or since the installer has fields elsewhere for user/pass

```
server.example.com/dbname
```

The installer includes a link to the EZConnect docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm.

All the examples in that doc include a forward slash.  But every combination I've tried results in an error like this:

```
Invalid database TNS "sever.example.com/service_name". Use only ASCII letters (a-z,     
A-Z), numbers (0-9), underscores (_) and dots (.).
```

I can't find any examples of EZConnect that don't include a forward slash.

That error is from Mediawiki, not Oracle.  I'm tailing the listener log and there is no connection made - Medaiwiki is returning an error without trying to connect.

I'm using php OCI8 with the Oracle instant client.  I don't have a tnsnames.ora setup for this client - which is kind of the point of EZConnect.  I did write a test php script that connects via oci_connect just fine.

Has anyone configured Mediawiki to use Oracle with EZConnect?  If so, what did you use in the installer?